# Test the various http content encodings?

Tags: apache, http, encoding

I'm building an application that makes HTTP requests to various servers (not controlled by me). As such, I need it to handle all possible `Content-Encoding` values properly (`gzip`, `compress`, `deflate`). In order to test my application I quickly installed Apache, but only to realize it only supports gzip compression. That is, if I send, for example, `Accept-Encoding: deflate`, it will not encode the response at all.

1. How can I enable `deflate` and `compress` encodings in Apache? or
2. Are there other, more useful tools for this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's just for testing, you can actually implement it yourself within PHP.

Answer (score 0):

[`mod_deflate`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html) should do the job

Comment: `mod_deflate` is enabled, but the server is not responding to `Accept-Encoding: deflate`.

Comment: Actually, `mod_deflate` does gzip compression. If I deactivate it I get uncompressed responses no matter what my `Accept-Encoding` is.